# Hide "Never Ask Again" checkbox using ionic

Tags: angular8, ionic5

I am using ionic 5 and i am implementing maps using Geo location plugin. Basically when the app is installed and opened for the first time, permission popup will be shown to the user. But inside this popup we can also see "Never ask again" option. Is there any way we can hide using ionic code?

Below is the screen shot of the same for reference.

[image]

Comment: is this system level dialog or browser? if it is standard system level dialog there is hardly an easy way to remove / customize it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. its on system(mobile device).